# Find communities in a large graph with million vertices in Python using igraph and leidenalg

Tags: python, graph, igraph

I am trying to get some experience with using igraph to find communities. Following the documentation and using the zachary karate club dataset, I was able to find the optimal number of communities with regards to modularity.

```
import leidenalg as la
import igraph as ig

file = 'data/com-dblp.ungraph.txt'

#G = ig.Graph.Read_Edgelist(file)
G = ig.Graph.Famous('Zachary')

partition = la.find_partition(G, la.ModularityVertexPartition)

print(partition)
print("Modularity of this partition: ", ig.Graph.modularity(G, partition))

ig.plot(partition)
```

Following is the output:

```
Clustering with 34 elements and 4 clusters
[0] 8, 9, 14, 15, 18, 20, 22, 26, 29, 30, 32, 33
[1] 0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 11, 12, 13, 17, 19, 21
[2] 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 31
[3] 4, 5, 6, 10, 16
Modularity of this partition:  0.4197896120973044
```

However, how can I move this approach to work with larger datasets like the DBLP dataset provided by Snap which has 317080 nodes? When I try the same approach it outputs 109092 clusters with modularity of 0.8288599603794473.

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify your question? It seems that `leidenalg` provides you a valid clustering, also for the DBLP dataset. (Disclaimer: I am the author of `leidenalg`).

Comment: @VincentTraag Thank you for your answer. The clusters that are outputted by leidenalg seem to classify almost every node as a single community. I guess this is normal since it tries to maximize the modularity. However, is there some way to access different partitions?

Comment: You can adjust the `resolution_parameter` when using the [`RBConfigurationVertexPartition`](https://leidenalg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#leidenalg.RBConfigurationVertexPartition). This is identical to ModularityVertexPartition, but has a resolution parameter that allows you to get a more refined (higher resolution) or a coarser (lower resolution) result. You might also check if some of the other quality functions provide more useful results for your dataset.